# get more fields with bibtex-completion-candidates

Tags: helm, bibtex

In Helm-bibtex the function `bibtex-completion-candidates`retrieves selected fields (authors, editors, title, year, type, and key of the
entry) from the `.bib` file. Is there a way to make it retrieve additional fields (eg `abstract` or `url` fields) into the the second (alist) element?

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation of the configuration variable `bibtex-completion-additional-search-fields`.  Example:

```
(setq bibtex-completion-additional-search-fields '(keywords))
```

See also the [documentation on GitHub](https://github.com/tmalsburg/helm-bibtex#fields-used-for-searching).